Why did the Iranian president use an old American helicopter?
Why did the Iranian president use such an old helicopter, and for which, being American-made, there were difficulties in procuring spare parts? Why Iran is not buying new Chinese or Russian helicopters?

Reuters reported on the 20th that Iran's state-run IRNA news agency reported that Raisi was riding a U.S.-made Bell-212 helicopter at the time of the accident.
The Bell-212 is a helicopter made by Bell Helicopter, an American defense contractor, that was first flown in 1968.link


Iran operates various helicopters, but international sanctions make it difficult to procure parts and maintain them properly. The helicopter involved in the incident was reportedly a Bell UH-1N Twin Huey, a utility military variant of the U.S.-made Bell 212. The UH-1N typically has a fifteen-seat configuration, with one pilot and fourteen passengers.  The U.S. delivered them to Iran as a high-priority customer directly before the revolution in 1979. link


Is there any evidence that the helicopter in question is actually that old?

It says right there that sanctions make it difficult to get the parts. Perhaps even from Russia or China. There were several resolutions from the whole Security Council that imposed sanctions on Iran, after all, starting nearly two decades ago. And even the sanctions from individual countries could cause foreign suppliers to not want to deal with Iran for fear of losing business.

Some of the Marine VH-3D fleet for the US President are only 10 years newer (1978).

@Obie2.0: I suppose the Q is why they didn't buy new Russian or Chinese helos. I think there's no prohibition on them buying that.

Also note that poor weather (fog) was a factor, if not the main factor for this crash. https://dims.apnews.com/dims4/default/8902184/2147483647/strip/true/crop/3377x2250+311+0/resize/767x511!/format/webp/quality/90/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fassets.apnews.com%2F27%2F48%2F853e46c1579c70a06d0e303b0851%2F062e059b3ca54b29bfc81f7ccb4a617d It's not clear if the helicopter had any tech issues. https://apnews.com/article/iran-president-ebrahim-raisi-426c6f4ae2dd1f0801c73875bb696f48 And they purchased that helo relatively recently "Iran purchased in the early 2000s".

@againstverylongusernames Very much true.  Mountainous terrain and bad weather, esp fog, makes for dangerous helicoptering.  That's true in British Columbia, that's true in Hawaii, that's true in LA (Kobe Bryant) that's true everywhere.

More modern hardware is also more susceptible to electronic interference.

Also training of pilots and maintenance crews is a factor on keeping existing equipment.

@SimonRichter are you thinking GSP spoofing, or messing with sea level à la Die Hard 2? I'm thinking that making Iran and North Korea (more?) paranoid is in Russia's best interest as it draws the "gang of four" (including China) closer. Then again, it was hard to imagine that Israel's recently targeting an antenna was the end of their response. Then again, sometimes a cigar is just a cigar.

Why weren't they using one of their own excellent drones or ballistic missiles for that in country trip, though I understand that they have reservations about Russian or Chinese helicopter safety.

... to get to the other side.

Note that "old" aircraft are still quite common almost everywhere.  I see the Bell 212 in particular fairly frequently in the US.  If you keep them properly maintained, aircraft can last a very long time (they're built to significantly higher standards than other vehicles like cars).

@JoeW The Bell 212 helicopter was produced from 1968-1998 - making it at best 26 years old or at worst 56 years old. From Wikipedia: "Much of Iran's military air fleet was acquired prior to the 1979 Revolution. The helicopter involved is estimated to be 40–50 years old, with serial number 35071 and aircraft registration number 6-9207 or 6-9221"

@DannyBeckett There is still a big difference between one made in 1979 and one made in 1998 and 26 years old isn't that old for a aircraft. I was simply looking for some sort of evidence that had the age of the helicopter besides a quote from the article.

Iran went through a major revolution in 1979, which later resulted in the Iran hostage crisis, where Iran stormed the US embassy and held hostages. As a result, Iran has been under an embargo from most Western nations.
A lot of what Iran has in terms of aircraft is pre-revolution Western-made. For instance, they still fly the ancient F-14 tomcat fighters (the US retired its F-14 fleet in 2006)

As of 2022, the F-14 remains in service with Iran's air force, though in low numbers of combat-ready aircraft due to a lack of spare parts.

Why not just buy from China or Russia? Part of that might be that Iran doesn't have a large economy (about $400B USD in GDP) or a lot of money. China and Russia want cash, not bartering for oil

“The key problem is Iran can’t pay dollars or euros in cash to China, [Iran] prefer using oil and natural gas to exchange weapons,” said Zhou Chenming, a researcher with the Yuan Wang think tank, a Beijing-based military science and technology institute.


Found on AtlanticCouncil: "In 2022, Iran bought $2.12 billion worth of machinery from China, as well as $1.43 billion worth of electronics." That's enough money to buy some  helicopters though. link

China needs oil. Now that the Russians have no better choice as to sell them, maybe not so strongly, but the same Russians can not buy much lesser amount of western goods for their dollars. Beside that, the ultimate $ location is the U.S. bank system and if an account is known Russian, it will be frozen. I think, today it would be better to sell oil to the Chinese for yuan, then buy helicopter from the Russians for the yuan, and the Russians will buy drones and weapon factories from the Chinese for the yuan. But it is a new thing, and that was probably a trusted helicopter of the government.

@GraySheep Yes, but it's clear China does not want a strict barter for their aircraft. And there's always the possibility that Iranian oil will be seized in transit.

@Arwenz Yes... but Iran currently is funding proxy groups as well. A country needs to buy a fleet to be cost effective, and that alone may be too much for Iran to bear.

@Arwenz Buying helicopters to ferry around a president with limited power (all real power is held by the Supreme Leader), who is only there so they can pretend they are a democracy, is probably not very high in their priorities. Did you even know his name before the accident? They prefer to spend what little hard currency they have elsewhere.

They actually make clones of Bell 214 helos. So this isn't entirely correct. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PANHA https://www.timesaerospace.aero/features/irans-helicopter-options And also some models that aren't straight clones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saba-248_(helicopter)

It’s not just one helicopter involved. Iran has a fleet  of five Bell 212 aircraft helicopters used for VIP  transport. Replacing them would have cost at least ten million dollars . In the days that  they were even more heavily  sanctioned it would not have been easy money to come by. There would also be other issues involved. A country as belligerent as Iran probably isn’t so interested  in having to to go to  other belligerent  countries like Russia and China for a new VIP squadron transport fleet. You never know what they might want in return for such an exchange knowing that  Iran is vulnerable and has no other options to replace that fleet.
Finally it probably wasn’t enough of  a priority for them. Things like replacing the VIP squadron transport fleets always have a lot of  bureaucracy and red tape involved. A country as belligerent and as war mongering  as Iran never  has safety high up on their list of priorities. Why worry about helicopters when you can be spending the time developing new  missiles and smuggling  money and weapons to terrorist groups around the world?

They actually make clones of Bell 214 helos. So this isn't entirely correct. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PANHA https://www.timesaerospace.aero/features/irans-helicopter-options And also some models that aren't straight clones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saba-248_(helicopter)

There may also be reasons for preferring military equipment to modern luxury transport helicopters. I'm not sure of the specifics, but it could include e.g. defensive abilities, reliability, capabilities (not including adverse weather I guess), availability of parts (more modern aircraft may have fewer sources of parts which could be sanctioned), the image projected from military craft (we're tough), or the political liability from spending lots of money on luxury aircraft.

Many crafts in Iran was once American built, but their parts have been changed so largely through years that now you may hardly call them American built, or any old either. Example are F-5 fighters, or its improved versions, which are built completely in Iran but you may see and think it is some decades old, which are not. I doubt if the helicopter is any such aged either ... the form and model might appear to be so, but the inner beast (which may be improved compared to the original model) might be not ... However, that doesn't mean that any and every part is built completely in Iran and not bought from abroad, and there is where you may find a place for sanctions making hard to purchase the parts. I do not know if this is an issue about this particular copter or not, but M.J. Zarif, the Prime Minister of the previous government in Iran, blamed US to have parts in this accident (like many other accidents that has happened to civilians in Iran, or lack of drugs and etc.) due to applying such sanctions.
